HECRAS 2D numerical solution: treatment of boundary conditions in Diffusion Wave Equation solver:
I'm trying to understand how boundary conditions are applied in the diffusion wave equation solver within HECRAS 2D (specifically, version 6.4). From my understanding, the solver:

simplifies the 2D shallow water equations (specifically, the momentum equation) by neglecting the following terms: inertia, Coriolis force, turbulence, wind stresses (I decided to neglect this), atmospheric pressure (I decided to neglect this), and flow drag.
Manning's equation is used to simplify bottom friction term
The obtained velocity is then substituted into the 2D mass conservation equation to form the diffusion wave equation (as shown in the attached equations).

Here’s where I'm getting confused:
Hydrograph Boundary Conditions: I initially thought that the flow (Q) specified in the hydrograph was simply applied as a source/sink term in the diffusion wave equation. However, in a lecture by Alex Sanchez (one of HECRAS's developers), he mentions that the entered energy gradient (EG) entered by the user is used to compute normal depth at the flow boundary. Can someone explain what this means? and how is it exactly implemented as a condition?
Normal Depth Calculation: How is the normal depth implemented in the solver? the user inputs a friction slope.
